# Angular - Diferencia entre Observable y Promise

Tags: angularjs, observable

Tengo entendido que un Observable es una promesa pero con filtros para poder realizar llamadas asíncronas sin tener que realizar muchas peticiones.

Creo que entiendo el concepto pero no lo tengo claro en la práctica.

¿Además de un buscador de palabras que otros ejemplos usarías un Observable y en qué otros un  Promise?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Promise**

Una `Promise` maneja un evento único cuando una operación asíncrona se completa o falla.

Hay bibliotecas de `Promise` por ahí que admiten cancelación, pero ES6 Promise no lo ha hecho hasta ahora. Por lo menos no que yo haya encontrado todavía.

**Observable**

Un `Observable` es un flujo de datos (`Stream` en otro lenguajes) y permite pasar cero o más eventos donde se invoca un callback para cada evento.

A menudo `Observable` se prefiere antes que `Promise` porque proporciona las características de `Promise` y mucho más. Con `Observable` no importa si querés manejar 0, 1 o varios eventos. Podés utilizar la misma API en cada caso.

`Observable` también tiene la ventaja sobre `Promise` de que se puede cancelar. Si el resultado de una solicitud HTTP a un servidor o alguna otra operación asíncrona costosa ya no es necesaria, la `Suscription` de un `Observable` permite cancelar la suscripción, mientras que una `Promise` eventualmente llamará al callback de éxito o rechazo, incluso si ya no lo necesitás mas.

`Observable` proporciona operadores como map(), forEach(), reduce(), ... similar a un array

También hay operadores poderosos como retry(), o replay(), que a menudo son muy útiles.

En mi caso, cuando empecé a usar `Observable`, me olvidé totalmente de `Promise`.

Espero que sea clara la explicación, en caso contrario, no dudes en preguntar todo lo que necesites.

Comment: Excelente tu explicación muchas gracias.

Comment: @KN_ Hola amigo. ando como loco buscando información para entender lo que son los observables. Leí tu respuesta y entiendo que todo aquello que se puede hacer con una promesa se podría hacer con un observable. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial e hicieron esto con una promesa:  ``` const getAll =  () => {

 return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  bd.query('SELECT * FROM usuario', (err,rows) => {
   return (err)? reject(err): resolve(rows);
  });
 });
}; ```  eso entonces podría sustituirlo por un observable ? sería ventajoso hacerlo con un observable ? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @JulianProg, buenas! podrías sustituirlo (igual habría que ver bien el ejemplo en el contexto para saber bien cómo). Si querés, lo podemos ver en un chat. Perdón la demora en la respuesta. Abrazo!

Comment: @KN_ Hola amigo, recién acabo de ver tu respuesta. aún ando tratando de entender esto de los observables, y el uso de algunos operadores de Rxjs. tendrías un tiempo para algunas consultas? por favor hazmelo saber, estaría enormemente agradecido. Si habilitas un chat para ello por favor avísame para entrar. Estaré atento. Saludos!

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un articulo muy interesante sobre que es, y como se usa el observable.
Espero te sea de ayuda :)

[Observables](https://codekstudio.com/post-blog/conceptos-observables-rxjs-y-angular-2-javascript-reactivo-y-funcional/57d1e2840897131b5ec54b90)