# Como obtener datos del servicio en el componente

Tags: angular

Tengo un suscribe en el servicio

```
getUsers() {
        const url: string = "http://localhost:8080/user/";

        this.http.get<Object[]>(url).subscribe( data => {
               return  this.listUsers = data
            }
        );
    }
```

ahora necesito obtener `this.listUsers` en el componente

Este es el componente

```
async ngOnInit() {
        this.listUsers=await this.datasService.getUsers();
        console.log('MENSAJE: ', this.listUsers);
    }
```

pero en el console obtengo `undefined`, como obtengo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devuelve el observable y suscríbete a él en el componente:

```
getUsers() {
    const url: string = "http://localhost:8080/user/";
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(url);
}
```

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.datasService.getUsers().subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data)
        }
    );
}
```

Nota: [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await) son nativos de Javascript y se pueden usar para esperar el resultado de una [promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise). Los observables que usa Angular no son Javascript nativo sino que provienen de una librería llamada [RxJs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/).

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/74930/angular-diferencia-entre-observable-y-promise

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener el resultado del llamado, tratar los datos en el mismo servicio, y regresarlos en una promesa.

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.listUsers = await this.datasService.getUsers().catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    console.log('MENSAJE: ', this.listUsers);
  }

  getUsers() {
    return new Promise((users, error) => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/';
      this.http.get(url).subscribe((data) => {
        users(data);
      }, (fail) => {
        error(fail);
      });
    });
  }
```